# Netsuite Suitescript Decode Base64

Tags: javascript, base64, netsuite, decode, suitescript2.0

I'm doing Api integration with Suitescript 2.0. A data encoded with base64 is returned from the Api. Here I need to reach the data I want by decoding the base64 and saving the xml data returned as a .zip and unzip it.

The relevant data can be run in Notepad++ with Plugins > MIME Tools > Decode Base64, saved as zip and opened with unzip.

The script I'm working with is a shcedule script.

I tried the two methods mentioned to decode in Suite Answers.

1- From base64 to UTF_8 with N/encode module (Returned result is completely wrong for this problem)

2 - The solution in the link:
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/41271/kw/base64%20decode

(In this solution, when you save the returned data as zip, it gives an "Unexpected end of the archive" error when opening the zip.)

ArrayBuffer() and atob() are not available in Suitescript.

Comment: If you use N/encode to get UTF-8 are you actually seeing xml?  Or is what you are retrieving zipped xml file transferred as base64?

What is your end goal -- is it to just save the xml.zip in the Netsuite file cabinet to be opened by users or do you need to process the contents? i.e. why do you care to save as a zip file? Just for space -- if so see the N/compress module

Answer (score 0):

The thing I know will work is to proxy the call through a Lambda on some external system.

However if your data is already in base64 you might try just creating a file cabinet file and give it the base64 encoded value as its content. Netsuite already handles base64 for files so you might be overworking the issue. It doesn't sound like you are actually processing the xml if your end goal is to save it as a zip.

If this doesn't help see my comments regarding some clarifications you could add to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(["N/encode"], function(encode){ 

 var txt = encode.convert({
            string: "your Base64 string",
            inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64,
            outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8
        });
}
```

[SuiteScript example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4369847722.html)

[All types of encode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4369865177.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).